# Exceptions: redirect or render?

Tags: exception, redirect, error-handling

I'm trying to standardize the way I handle exceptions in my web application (homemade framework) but I'm not certain of the "correct" way to handle various situations.  I'm wondering if there is a best practice from UI/ user-friendly point of view.

1. User logs into application and opens two tabs showing the same screen.  On one tab they issue a delete command on object `FOO`.  Then, in the other tab they then click the edit command on `FOO` (which no longer exists); e.g. a GET request for `editObject.php?object_id=FOO`.  What should I do when they issue the edit request for this nonexistent object?

   -Currently I am redirecting these "missing" objects to the previous page with an error message like "object does not exist".
2. User issues a GET request to search for Objects with `color=Red`, e.g. `searchObjects.php?color=Red`.  The query returning these results blew up because somebody dropped the OBJECTS table.  This is an unexpected exception and isn't quite the same as 1).

   -Currently I am redirecting to `errorPage.php` with a message "Unexpected error"
3. In general, what should I do if GET/POST parameters that *should* be there are instead mysteriously missing.  Perhaps somebody is trying to inject something?

   -Currently I am treating these the same as 2)

---

What should I be doing in each of the above 3 cases?

1. Render a "Object does not exist" view at the url `editObject.php?object_id=FOO`
2. Redirect to a controller that displays an error view: `header('Location: errorPage.php')`
3. Serve a 404: not sure of the syntax for doing this in PHP/Apache
4. Other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say render it and serve a 404. That way, the user has the chance to see where they went wrong in the URL, or copy & paste it. If you redirect to a generic error page, they don't have that chance.

The PHP way to serve a 404 is

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 not found");
```